# Force orientation in ios9

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape, landscape-portrait

I want to force portrait mode in 2 viewController and 1 viewController with landscape mode,
I have tried older technique , but those are not working in ios9

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely that you've got some allowed orientations defined in your `info.plist`. You should check there and remove any entries, as I believe these will override any other values in the project.

You should then be able to set the orientation on each VC with something like:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}
```

I think the key you need to is `Supported interface orientations`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation of the viewcontroller from Xib/Storyboard as each viewcontroller have the property "orientation"

and implement method given below

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if they have overridden `Supported interface orientations` in their `info.plist`

Comment: i have removed  Supported interface orientations key from plist . Then too it is not working , This method not called .

Answer (score 0):

You can set orientation as bellow in your viewDidAppear method

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: This is working if my viewcontroller is initial viewcontroller , But in which viewcontroller i want to lock orientation is not initial viewcontroller

Comment: I have checked in other viewcontroller and it is working fine